# show that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ is $O(n^3)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

To start, am I on the right track?

$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ = $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2 \le n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + ... + n^2$

Where would I go from here?

Comment: If you already know how to sum squares, the formula tells you right away (hint)

Comment: Your inequality is also very close to the result you want to show. How many terms of $n^2$ do you have? (We don't really care about the exact constant involved in the formula for summation of squares when dealing with big-O notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *so* close.

I will write what you did
using summation notation
and finish it.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
&\le \sum_{i=1}^n n^2
\qquad\text{since } i \le n\\
&= n^2\sum_{i=1}^n 1
\qquad\text{taking }n^2\text{ out of the sum}\\
&= n^3
\qquad\text{since }\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n\\
\end{array}
$

Here's a more general case.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^m
&\le \sum_{i=1}^n n^m
\qquad\text{since } i \le n\\
&= n^m\sum_{i=1}^n 1
\qquad\text{taking }n^m\text{ out of the sum}\\
&= n^{m+1}
\qquad\text{since }\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n\\
\end{array}
$

This shows that
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^m
=O(n^{m+1})
$.

Answer (score 1):

The brute force approach:

We have

$\sum_1^n i^2 = \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}, \tag{1}$

which is in fact *very* well known--just google something like "sum of first n squares"; you'll get about a gazillion hits.

It's pretty easy to prove (1) by induction; for $n = 1$ we see that (1) reduces to

$1^2 = 1 = \dfrac{1(2)(3)}{6}; \tag{2}$

just for the fun of it we check the cases $n = 2, 3$:

$1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5 =  \dfrac{2(3)(5)}{6}; \tag{3}$

$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 1 + 4 + 9 = 14 = \dfrac{3(4)(7)}{6}; \tag{4}$

from here, a simple inductive step carries the day:  if

$\sum_1^k i^2 = \dfrac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6}, \tag{5}$

then

$\sum_1^{k + 1} i^2 = \sum_1^k i^2 + (k + 1)^2 = \dfrac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6} + (k + 1)^2; \tag{6}$

we grind on the right hand side:

$\dfrac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6} + (k + 1)^2 = \dfrac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1)}{6} + \dfrac{6(k + 1)^2}{6}$
$= \dfrac{k(k + 1)(2k + 1) + 6(k + 1)^2}{6}; \tag{7}$

now,

$k(k + 1)(2k + 1) = (k^2 + k)(2k + 1) = 2k^3 + 3k^2 + k, \tag{8}$

and so

$k(k + 1)(2k + 1) + 6(k + 1)^2 = 2k^3 + 3k^2 + k + 6k^2 + 12k + 6$
$= 2k^3 + 9k^2 + 13k + 6, \tag{9}$

and also

$(k + 1)(k + 2)(2(k +1) + 1) = (k^2 + 3k + 2)(2k + 3)$
$= 2k^3 + 3k^2 + 6k^2 + 9k + 4k + 6 = 2k^3 + 9k^2 + 13k + 6, \tag{10}$

so we see that

$k(k + 1)(2k + 1) + 6(k + 1)^2 = (k + 1)(k + 2)(2(k + 1) + 1), \tag{11}$

and combining (6), (7), and (11):

$\sum_1^{k + 1} = \dfrac{(k + 1)(k + 2)(2(k + 1) + 1)}{6}, \tag{12}$

which completes the inductive step and allows us to conclude that

$\sum_1^n i^2 = \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} \tag{12}$

for all positive integers $n$.  Using (8), we write (12) as

$\sum_1^n i^2 = \dfrac{2n^3 + 3n^2 + n}{6} = n^3\dfrac{2 + 3n^{-1} + n^{-2}}{6};  \tag{13}$

since

$\dfrac{2 + 3n^{-1} + n^{-2}}{6} \to \dfrac{1}{3}  \tag{14}$

as $n \to \infty$, we see that

$\sum_1^n i^2 = O(n^3).  \tag{15}$

Answer (score 0):

> It's equivalent to

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2} \over n^{3}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\left(\,n + 1\,\right)^{2} \over \left(\,n + 1\,\right)^{3} - n^{3}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\left(\,1 + 1/n\,\right)^{2} \over 3 + 3/n + 1/n^{2}}\ =\ \bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\displaystyle{1 \over 3}}
$$